# something went wrong with my code while rearranging elements of $_FILES

Tags: php, mkdir

I have created some basic script to upload images over http/s and as all of you know that working with $_FILES GLOBAL array is a bit uncomfortable, so I decided to write a `reArranger` for $_FILES GLOBAL array. I have written two functions for doing the same thing. but one of them is not working properly. I can't get familiar with that misunderstanding. could u help me to find out my mistake!?

openserver 5.9, php7.2 apache2.4

This is an index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload and Display post images</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>

<form action="receive.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
     Send these files:<br />
      <input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="files"/><br /><br />
      <input name="upload"  id="submitUpload" type="submit" value="Send files" />
  </div>
</form>

<br />
<br />
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<script>

</script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

last one is upload.php

```
    /* this function gets all images' names, and other variables in good format */
    public function getImages($img = array()){

        #$html = file_get_contents('phpinfo.php');
        #printf($html);
        #$html  = substr($html, 4, 0);
        #return $html;


        for($i = 0; $i < @count($img['userfile']['name']); $i++) {
            $this->img_arr[$i]['name'] = $img['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $this->img_arr[$i]['type'] = $img['userfile']['type'][$i];
            $this->img_arr[$i]['tmp_name'] = $img['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        }
        return $this->img_arr;
    }





    protected function reArrangeFiles(array $files){


    foreach($files['userfile'] as $name => $value){
        #echo $name;

        for($i=0;$i<count($files['userfile'][$name]);$i++ ){
            $rearranged[$i][$name] = $files['userfile'][$name][$i];
        }
    }
    return $rearranged;

}
```

in upload class there are 2 funcs that rearrange $_FILES's elements but one of them(it is reArrangeFiles) does not return correctly. what is wrong with my func?

I want to get the same result as I  get from getImages method. I have cut other part of code because while creating question I was asked not write whole file.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote function and now it should be working as you want it :)

If you don't want to return them in numerical array, replace `$rearranged[$filename][$k] = $value;` with `$rearranged[][$k] = $value;`

```
protected function reArrangeFiles(array $files){
    foreach ($files['userfile'] as $k => $filesArray) {
        foreach($filesArray as $filename => $value) {
            $rearranged[$filename][$k] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $rearranged;
}
```

Comment: when I run then I use one of them for rearranging, but they work differently. I want to know what is wrong with my reArrangeFiles  func. I don't pass the result of first func to reArrangeFiles func. I pass $_FILES to one of them. but as I mentioned getImages is working fine. second one is not!

Comment: I edited my answer and rewrote function. Please check if it is working as you want.